# Can I use a PC controller on my Xbox one?

Tags: pc, controllers, xbox-one

I don't want to spend money on a new Xbox One controller so I'm trying to figure out some other way to play.

I understand that you can play on PC with an Xbox One controller, but does it work the other way - Can I use a PC controller on my Xbox One?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "PC" controller. PC is a generic term these days and the fact that Microsoft designed the XBOne controller to be the same controller for Windows Gaming, they become interchangeable in the context of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean with "pc controller".

You definitely **CAN NOT** use any other controller than the Xbox One controller to play on a Xbox One!

But a Xbox One controller can be used with a PC via cable and/or if wireless via the respective wireless stick.

Comment: You can buy third-party (non-Microsoft-branded) Xbox One controllers and use those, but they are still "Xbox One" controllers first and foremost.

Comment: And the [HOTAS](https://venturebeat.com/2017/12/11/thrustmasters-xbox-one-hotas-joystick-is-excellent-if-you-love-elite-dangerous/), but it's only good for one game at the moment that I know of. And again, the Xbox version, not any old HOTAS.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, these guys are actually incorrect.

I bought a wireless off brand controller off Amazon. It doesn’t do the regular connection, it uses a USB dongle that plugs into front of Xbox and it works fine!
I’ve also used keyboard and mouse wirelessly and wired. And a Razer 18key pad controller and a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Misinformation. This is "typical" people responding with what they think they know and, doing "ZERO" actual research.

Sony and Microsoft finally showed true intelligence & foreward thinking with realizing people were making a decision on what console they were going to buy based solely on their ptefered controller. I THINK the only thing that is kept top secret is Bluetooth. I have never seen a third-party controller with Bluetooth, they're always wired, even Razors Wolverine ultimate $160 (last I checked) is wired. And if Razer doesn't have Bluetooth connectivity I doubt any other company does. What third parties are doing now is releasing Xbox one  & PS5 styled controllers.

So now you can play on your favorite console or PC with your favorite controller. Some companies do have wireless versions, but I would stay away from them because what they have to do would create a lot of input lag so if it's not a wireless controller from Microsoft or Sony I would go with a wired controller from a reputable company such as Razer, Logitech, etc...

TLDR: Microsoft and Sony saw a benefit in selling their controllers to all of their customers. So you can now use YOUR FAVORITE controller with Xbox/Xbox One/PS5/Win10/Android/iOS.

BUYER BEWARE: Be skeptical of any other wireless controller NOT made by Microsoft/Sony, it's HIGHLY UNLIKELY it would use Bluetooth, they are using some other wireless transmission. Fine for a printer, NOT for gaming. My 2 cents.

Comment: While this could be true for next gen consoles, OP is asking about old Xbox One (since it's a 2016 question...)

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. You can connect it to your pc and then, if you have windows 10, you can use the xbox app to stream it to your computer and use the controller.

Comment: And how would I do that? Do you have any documentation or any more descriptive reference on how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm, you cannot unless it is a controller specifically made to function for Xbox One (official or third-party).

I have tried, via USB, a PlayStation 4 controller and Google Stadia controller (which now runs as a standard controller), and neither of them work on the Xbox One - they both work on a PC though.

A Xbox Series X|S controller is backwards compatible with Xbox One.